# Print Spooler Crashing After KB4561608 with Ricoh Printers

Tags: windows, print-server

I have a few computers that received the June update for windows 10 1809 that are now unable to print and event viewer is logging the following error:

```
    Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          6/10/2020 10:14:13 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      xxxxx
Description:
Faulting application name: rundll32.exe_printui.dll, version: 10.0.17763.1, time stamp: 0x9816818b
Faulting module name: gdi32full.dll, version: 10.0.17763.1282, time stamp: 0xf9833b72
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x0000000000079de0
Faulting process id: 0x2134
Faulting application start time: 0x01d63f3166e8602b
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
Report Id: 421704c0-6592-4c05-9063-e8f915744f9f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-06-10T14:14:13.459240800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>79590</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>xxx</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>rundll32.exe_printui.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.17763.1</Data>
    <Data>9816818b</Data>
    <Data>gdi32full.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.17763.1282</Data>
    <Data>f9833b72</Data>
    <Data>c000041d</Data>
    <Data>0000000000079de0</Data>
    <Data>2134</Data>
    <Data>01d63f3166e8602b</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll</Data>
    <Data>421704c0-6592-4c05-9063-e8f915744f9f</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

This problem seems to only affect Ricoh printers. Any idea what the fix is other than removing the update?

Comment: Hi, did you checked if Ricoh published a new driver version in response to that kb ?

Comment: I confirm this problem with Panasonic KX-MB263RU and KB4560960 as well. Here the details for my case, if anybody interested: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-any-program-crashesfreezes-when-trying/954dc5b1-7be4-43a0-938c-a9a20c4b3b7a?tm=1592931580635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some discussion [elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/gzbivo/patch_tuesday_megathread_20200609/ftkus8l/) indicates this only affects PCL5 drivers, not PCL6 or PS. Can you try a different driver for the Ricoh printers?

Comment: I can confirm that the PCL5 drivers are affected. Using the PCL 6 drivers solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Same here with HP Designjet 111. Unfortunetly there is no other driver available. Removing KB4560960 resolved the issue.

Comment: Microsoft released the following statement: After installing this update, certain printers might fail to print. The print spooler might throw an error or close unexpectedly when attempting to print, and no output will come from the affected printer.

You might also encounter issues with the apps you are attempting to print from. You might receive an error from the app or the app might close unexpectedly.
Note This issue might also affect software-based printers, for example printing to PDF.
Microsoft is working on a resolution and will provide an update when more information is available.

Comment: Here is the KB see the known issues section: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4560960

Comment: Update: This issue was resolved with the update that was released 6/16/2020

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue, even with the latest PCL6 drivers for our Ricoh printer. Removing KB4560960 resolved the issue.. This is the equivalent update for build 1903.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. It happened on three different devices and on different Windows versions (which is 1809, 1909, and 2004). My printer is Ricoh Aficio MP4001. I have to remove the update on all 3 devices, then the printing worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Also KB4557957 cause the problem. Removing it resolve the problem.